# MySQL - Double primary key in EER table

Tags: mysql

## Context

I have been fiddling with a small fooseball hobby database to keep track of matches, players and goals. And came across a problem i don't quite know how to fix.

The match table has two foreign keys both pointing to tID in the team table.
The thought was that i later would be able to do a SELECT to see what teams (by name) played against eachother in a given match.

```
select * from `Fooseball`.`match`
INNER JOIN team T1
ON Fooseball.`match`.mHome_Team = T1.tID
INNER JOIN team T2
ON Fooseball.`match`.mAway_Team = T2.tID
WHERE mID=1
```

[image: Result]

[image]

## Question

1 Is their a better way to archive this, than creating two primary keys. Like, an intermediate table?

2 How can i construct my select statement so i can name the tName columns as "home" and "away" or something else? When i try and say

```
INNER JOIN team AS T1
```

Nothing changes.

Comment: The `match` table has two ***foreign*** keys pointing to `team`. `match` has ***one*** primary key, which is `mID`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unstated additional requirements notwithstanding, this is pretty much how I would do it.

To rename columns in the result, you would do something like

```
SELECT m.mDate AS match_date, T1.tName AS home_team, T2.tName AS away_team
  FROM Fooseball.`match` m
  INNER JOIN team T1
    ON m.mHome_Team = T1.tID
  INNER JOIN team T2
    ON m.mAway_Team = T2.tID
  WHERE mID=1
```

For reporting, you can alias your columns with mixed case and spaces (eg. "Home Team") by enclosing the alias in double quotes.